# Easiest way to combine 2 double array sets into one finding their unions and intersections

Tags: c++, oop

I've been trying to get this done but i'm stuck right now. Can anyone please recommend the easiest way to get it done? Thank you

```
c[i] = a[i] + b[i];

// The snippet of code I have above works fine with operator: + - / * 
// a[i] = { 1, 8, 13, 15 }
// b[i] = { 3, 8, 13, 20 }
// then  c[i] = { 4, 16, 26, 35 }

// But how do i find the union and intersection of both arrays?
// I want the results to look like:
// union = {1,3,8,13,15,20}
// intersection = {8,13}
```

Comment: C++ has no such thing as a "double array set".

Answer (score 2):

since you asked for easiest way.
you can put the elements of the arrays into 2 std::set

```
std::set<T> set1(begin(array1), end(array1));
std::set<T> set2(begin(array2), end(array2));
```

Then use std::set_union and std::set_intersection in 2 new std::set.
Please take a look at the way its done in these links [set union](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/) and [set intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/)
Thus STL takes care of most of the logic and containers.

Comment: OP may just `std::sort` the 2 arrays instead of inserting them in `std::set` (OP may have to use `std::unique` if doublon have to be removed as in `std::set`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
//Unioin of 2 array

#include<stdio.h>

int printUnion(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n)
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while(i < m && j < n)
  {
    if(arr1[i] < arr2[j])
      printf(" %d ", arr1[i++]);
    else if(arr2[j] < arr1[i])
      printf(" %d ", arr2[j++]);
    else
    {
      printf(" %d ", arr2[j++]);
      i++;
    }
  }


  while(i < m)
   printf(" %d ", arr1[i++]);
  while(j < n)
   printf(" %d ", arr2[j++]);
}


int main()
{
  int arr1[] = {1, 8, 13, 15};
  int arr2[] = {3, 8, 13, 20};
  int m = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
  int n = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
  printUnion(arr1, arr2, m, n);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}


//Intersection of two array

#include<stdio.h>

int printIntersection(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n)
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while(i < m && j < n)
  {
    if(arr1[i] < arr2[j])
      i++;
    else if(arr2[j] < arr1[i])
      j++;
    else /* if arr1[i] == arr2[j] */
    {
      printf(" %d ", arr2[j++]);
      i++;
    }
  }
}


int main()
{
  int arr1[] = {1, 8, 13, 15};
  int arr2[] = {3, 8, 13, 20};
  int m = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
  int n = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
  printIntersection(arr1, arr2, m, n);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```